# Cross Apply error with Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When using CROSS APPLY in Oracle query i got SQL command not properly ended error
Here is the query

select * 
from Session_Dept 
cross apply(select * from Session_Employee
             WHERE Session_Employee.Id= Session_Dept.Id);

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Which version of Oracle? The `cross apply` syntax was added in 12c; it looks like you're using an earlier version?

Comment: Database version is 11g, then this is the reason. Thanks Alex